# d3.js Error data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new with d3.js and I'm trying to build a bar chart with a json file. Here is my code :

```
// scale to ordinal because x axis is not numerical
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]);

//scale to numerical value by height
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var chart = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg") //append svg element inside #chart
    .attr("width", width + (2 * margin.left) + margin.right) //set width
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom); //set height
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(); //orient bottom because x-axis will appear below the bars

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft();

d3.json("coucou.json", function (error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.time
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.value
    })]);

    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            return "translate(" + x(d.receive_date) + ", 0)";
        });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.responses);
        })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return x.rangeBand() + (margin.left / 2);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.responses);
        })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand()); //set width base on range on ordinal data

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", x.rangeBand() + margin.left)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.responses) - 10;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.responses;
        });

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("responses");
});
```

And my json file:

```
[{
    "data": [{
            "time": "11:30:00",
            "value": 121863
        },
        {
            "time": "11:35:00",
            "value": 121822
        },
        {
            "time": "11:40:00",
            "value": 121528
        },
        {
            "time": "11:45:00",
            "value": 121288
        }
    ]
}]
```

When I load my html page, I have this error : **TypeError: data.map is not a function** on this line :

```
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.time
    }));
```

I don't understand why. Did the syntax has changed with a new version ? But I don't find the way to write it...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What version of d3 are you using?

Comment: With the 4th version I have the **Uncaught TypeError** and with the 5th I don't have any error but nothing appear

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your json data? would be easier to help

Comment: of course ! I edit my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things I had to change.

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x); 

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
```

You forgot to add `(x)` & `(y)`

```
var chart = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Append the `g` alongside the chart variable, it's a lot easier

In your data snippet there were no `d.responses` so I changed it to `d.value`

And here's how you'd acces your json data

```
var data = data1[0].data;
```

Here's a working [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0DD2RIGtLnjB9ZOTz6js?p=preview)

Comment: @MissKnacki What browser are you using? I've tested it in ie, firefox and chrome and I don't get the error, at what line is the error? Try changing `let margin` to `var margin`. it's the only potential error that I can see.

Comment: I'm usually using Firefox but I have the same error with Chrome. The error is : `ReferenceError: g is not defined` at this line `.append(g)`. I try to change `let margin` to var margin but it doesn't come from there

Comment: I don't have any g tag in my html, is that where the problem come from ?

Comment: @MissKnacki go to the plunker link and copy paste *all* the code there that I've written and try again

Comment: @MissKnacki did you change the `let` to a `var`?

Comment: Yes, but nothing is changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171752/discussion-between-robert-andersson-and-missknacki).

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because the data was not loading completely the way the example is. So I fixed the error doing this:

```
 var dataCsv = d3.csv("../dashboard/sample-dataset.csv");

 dataCsv.then(function (data) {

  ...
  your function
  ...
  
 });
```